# PHP: How to export email from table

Tags: php, sql, export

I have 1000 email and i wont to export it from table. But i need between emails the " , " mark.

How can i do that.

Bets

Comment: Do it from inside PHPmyadmin.

Comment: What do you mean *`"But i need between emails the " , " mark"`*?

Comment: export it from phpmyadmin fo to any editor search and replace?

Comment: SELECT ws_concat(",",emails) FROM .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use GROUP_CONCAT (will automatically output values with "," mark)

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(email) 
from table
```